# I can't echo the same data in the next page

Tags: php, mysql

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
    echo("<a href='content.php'>".strtoupper($row['place'])."</a><br>");
    $row++;
}
```

I just printed the `$place` values in the page. When I click on them, `content.php` opens. Now, how can echo the same `$row['place']` value in `content.php`? Please help

Comment: Any pretty basic tutorial available via your favorite search engine will yield many results

Comment: if the variable is going to be used in a query, please do not forget to use prepared statements ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a parameter to `content.php` telling it which place you clicked on:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
    echo("<a href='content.php?id={$row['id']}'>".strtoupper($row['place'])."</a><br>");
    $row++;
}
```

Then `content.php` uses `$_GET['id']` to look up the appropriate place in the database.

Comment: How can we tell all the upcoming pages that we clicked in `$row['place'] ??

Comment: Set a session variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use get method. For example;

```
echo("<a href='content.php?data=".strtoupper($row['place'])."'>".strtoupper($row['place'])."</a><br>");
```

in content.php;

```
echo $_GET['data'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the `$row['place']` value with `<a>` tag as QueryString parameter.
Try this :-

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {
    echo("<a href='content.php?place=".$row['place']."'>".strtoupper($row['place'])."</a><br>");
}
```

You can access the place variable on `content.php` using `$_GET['place']`
(I don't know what's the use of `$row++` here)